# Plugin is working in Intellij but not in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I wrote a plugin in intellij which uses com.android.ddmlib.IDevice.installPackage method fro pushing the app to device , when I run the plugin in Intellij its working fine(the plugin works on android app) but the plugin jar is not working in Android Studio when I try to run the jar. The error says "No Such Method Exception:com.android.ddmlib.IDevice.installPackage". Should I include any Intellij specific packages in the test app, which is not a good practice?
Or there is any other way.